# What is down sampling and up sampling in iPhone resolution?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am following this link for iPhone device resolution guide. Since long while i am facing couple of words like DownSampling, UpSampling and Display Zoom on this [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). But i am confused with Physical Pixels and Rendered Pixels.

Does not getting which resolution to use when adding images ?

Please explain this situation , if any of know it in detail.
Thanks

Comment: for instace you can take a look [on this page](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions), which explains you.

Comment: Already attached link in question, but not understanding some terms.

Comment: which terms make you life difficult? it is mostly explaining what _upsampling_ and _downsampling_ mean in practice.

Comment: In this site iPhone 6 displaying two different Point coordinate calculation. 320*568 with Display Zoom and 375*667 without display zoom. I am not getting this point.

Comment: the __first iPhone6__ column shows what happens when your app supports only iPhone5 screen size and in that case _upsampling_ happens (no letterboxing); the __second iPhone6__ column show no up- or downsampling happens when your app supports iPhone6 screen size.

Comment: So it suggesting that iPhone 5 screen UpSampling to fit in 750 * 1334. So in this case it will cause distortion of image.

Comment: yes, both _upsampling_ and _downsampling_ can be considered as a kinda digital-zooming of the images, and both might cause distortion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display Zoom is a function of the larger iPhone models to use a lower "virtual resolution" in order to make things appear bigger on screen. The user can turn this on and off.

Display Zoom results in the UI being rendered at a resolution that does not match the actual screen resolution. For example, iPhone 6 has a native screen resolution of 750 × 1334, but you can run it at 640 x 1136.
So the display hardware will blow up the pixels to fill the screen. This is called upsampling.

The opposite effect also happens with the iPhone 6 Plus: It renders at 1242 × 2208, which is more pixels than the screen actually has. Here the display hardware downsamples.

Both techniques have traditionally been frowned upon, because it looks blurry/weird/pixelated if pixels have to be fudged that way, but it seems that with these very high resolution screens we now have the pixels are so small that it has become acceptable.

All this is done by the phone itself, your graphics assets and pixel calculations should all be done based on the "virtual" screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks Thilo , but In this site iPhone 6 displaying two different Point coordinate calculation. 320*568 with Display Zoom and 375*667 without display zoom. I am not getting this point.

Comment: The native resolution of iPhone 6 is 375*667@2x = 750x1334 pixels. With Display Zoom, iPhone 6 simulates the iPhone 5 display. This will make things look bigger. iPhone 5 has 320*568 points resolution @2x = 640 x 1136 pixels. You need to design your app to look good on iPhone4,5,6,6Plus (all of which have different resolutions).